# Porque tengo que usar break en este codigo?

Tags: python

Estoy haciendo este proyecto en el colegio, y no se porque tengo que añadir break solo para cuando ganas y no para cuando pierdes, no entiendo muy bien para que hace falta el break ya que cuando tu pones no en el input no debería parar el código??

```
import random
resp="Si"
while resp=="Si":
  intentos=6
  numerosecreto=random.randint(0,100)
  while not intentos==0:
    num=input("¿Cuál crees que es el número secreto?: ")
    while not num.isdigit():
      print("Tienes que escribir un número")
      num=input("¿Cuál crees que es el número secreto?: ")
    if int(num) > numerosecreto:
      intentos=intentos-1
      print("Incorrecto, el número es más pequeño. Te quedan "+str(intentos)+" intentos")  
    elif int(num) < numerosecreto:
      intentos=intentos-1
      print("Incorrecto, el número es más grande. Te quedan "+str(intentos)+" intentos")
    elif int(num)==numerosecreto:
      print("¡Has adivinado el numero en el intento número "+str((6-intentos)+1))
      resp=input("Quieres seguir jugando? (Si/No)")
      break
    if intentos==0:
      print("¡Has perdido, el número era "+str(numerosecreto))
      resp=input("¿Quieres seguir jugando? (Si/No)")
```

Comment: Porque cuando ganas lo  mas intentos sigue siendo distinto de 0 por lo tanto el ciclo donde preguntas el número secreto se volvaria a repetir aunque tu respuesta sea No. Ya que el while que comprueba la respuesta no correrá hasta que termine el while que pide el numero secreto

Answer (score 1):

El ciclo `while` continuara ejecutándose hasta que `intentos` llegue a cero, sin importar si el jugador adivinó o no el número.

Si el jugador adivina antes de los seis intentos, hay que romper el ciclo con un `break` y salir de él.

Sin embargo, la salida es condicional a que el jugadores responda "No". Te falta agregar un `if` para validar esa condición:

```
  resp=input("Quieres seguir jugando? (Si/No)")
  if resp.lower() == "no":
    break
```

#### Demo

```
import random
resp="Si"
while resp=="Si":
  intentos=6
  numerosecreto=random.randint(0,100)

  while intentos:
    num=input("¿Cuál crees que es el número secreto?: ")

    while not num.isdigit():
      print("Tienes que escribir un número")
      num=input("¿Cuál crees que es el número secreto?: ")

    if int(num) > numerosecreto:
      intentos=intentos-1
      print("Incorrecto, el número es más pequeño. Te quedan "+str(intentos)+" intentos")
    elif int(num) < numerosecreto:
      intentos=intentos-1
      print("Incorrecto, el número es más grande. Te quedan "+str(intentos)+" intentos")
    elif int(num)==numerosecreto:
      print("¡Has adivinado el numero en el intento número "+str((6-intentos)+1))
      resp=input("Quieres seguir jugando? (Si/No)")
      if resp.lower() == "no":
        break

    if intentos==0:
      print("¡Has perdido, el número era "+str(numerosecreto))
      resp=input("¿Quieres seguir jugando? (Si/No)")
```

produce:

```
¿Cuál crees que es el número secreto?: 50
Incorrecto, el número es más grande. Te quedan 5 intentos
¿Cuál crees que es el número secreto?: 75
Incorrecto, el número es más pequeño. Te quedan 4 intentos
¿Cuál crees que es el número secreto?: 60
¡Has adivinado el numero en el intento número 3
Quieres seguir jugando? (Si/No)No

Process finished with exit code 0
```